# Maximum input voltage ripple for FOC ESC

Tags: voltage, motor-controller, ripple

I designed a FOC ESC using TMS320F28027, DRV8305 and InstaSpin-FOC. Everything works great and it spins different motors very well.

I want to choose input bulk capacitors for it and I wonder what is acceptable voltage ripple on the input power.

I am trying different kinds of capacitors with different capacitances and get varying results (from 1V to 15V ripple). So, what is acceptable?

The system is powered via 22.2V 10Ah LiPo battery. The motor is 5212 BLDC with max currend draw 30A. Wires from battery to ESC are 60cm.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: 1V or 15V ripple are probably neither acceptable but you have to decide not us.

Comment: What are the factors that should influence the decision?

Comment: Too big to answer without focussing on a specific circuit and power supply hence, you need to provide more details about the power supply, the drive circuit and how the two interconnect. From this will come other questions like what motors are you using etc....

Comment: Added some info.